# How to find the limits along the line $y = mx$

Tags: calculus, limits

> **Problem**: Find the limits along the line $y=mx$
> $$
> \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2x^2}{2x^2+2y^2}
> $$

**Attempt**:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x^2}{2x^2+2m^2x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{2m^2x^2}
$$

Is that right?

Comment: @LostinSpace could you tell me how to correct it? As you can see I am attempting to solve this. Just that answer, doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron could I ask why do we cancel x^2?

Comment: You can't cancel an addend, only a factor. So factor $x^2$ out of the denominator, then cancel that.

Comment: @Sampaguita  Is this a new cancellation formula?

Comment: $\frac{2x^{2}}{2x^{2}(1+m^{2})}=\frac{1}{1+m^{2}}$

Comment: It’s wrong. That cancellation would be right if you had $\cdot$ instead of $+$

Comment: @MPW thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Michaël I'll keep that in mind. Thank you!

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron giving a lil bit of mix signals when you suggested to cancel x^2 at first and you're coming to me in that tone when we are both wrong.

Comment: Nothing wrong with canceling $x^2$ !!!IF!!! you cancel it as a *multiplicative* factor.  !!!NOT!!! and added factor $\require{cancel}$ $\frac {4}{4 + 12} \ne \frac {\cancel 4}{\cancel 4 + 12} =\frac 1{1+12}= \frac 1{13}$ but $\frac {4}{4+12} = \frac 4{4(1 + 3)}=\frac {\cancel 4}{\cancel 4(1+3)} = \frac 1{1+3}=\frac 14$ is fine.

Comment: @Sampaguita You WERE required to cancel(remove) the $x^{2}$ from the denominator . I decided to elaborate . Since you are asking about limit's you are expected to be well versed in primary grade algebra . Hence the sarcastic tone . You gotta admit, that was one heck of a weird way of cancelling . Anyways , sorry if you took offense.

Comment: So $\require{cancel}$$\frac {2x^2}{2x^2 + 2m^2x^2}=$$\frac {\cancel{2x^2}}{\cancel {2x^2} + 2m^2x^2}$$=\frac 1{2x^2m^2}$ is just plain wrong. but $\frac {2x^2}{2x^2 + 2m^2x^2} =\frac{2x^2}{2x^2(1 + m^2)}=\frac{\cancel{2x^2}}{\cancel{2x^2}(1+m^2)}=\frac 1{1+m^2}$ is just plain right.  It was perhaps rude to say "what kinda wacky way to cancel out common factors did you learn" but ... in all honesty, one is expected to have *mastered* these basics of factoring and reducing skills before starting calculus.

Comment: @fleablood clearly, there's no category for people returning to studies to you people. I'm trying to learn and relearn, so what's the problem in making a mistake? That's why I was asking. Not to be criticized of what I should and already know.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron As you can see, I'm trying to learn and relearn. What's the point in asking and making a mistake if I'll just be mocked at? I didn't just simply say just tell me the answer. I asked a question where I have also attempted myself. Yes, it's offensive. You people are in a high horse, you don't even know my situation.

Comment: Whoah....when did anyone "criticize" you ? . You made an error which by a calculus student standards was an unexpected and trivial one. In any case I have retracted my comment and apologized. If everyone just flipped out for a simple comment then it's better that no one talked ever. Why are you taking it as a personal attack ? .  Many times in this site people post questions which involves solution verifications like yours and often it turns out to be a trivial mistake. I don't think that looking at a "silly" mistake in a "silly" and non-serious way has any harm to it.

Comment: And not only that, when you say "you people" you are addressing the entire community rather than just me . Even if my comment can be construed as "offensive" in an exceedingly PC world , it does not give you to make a generic statement like "you people are in a high horse" .

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron You think this is the first time I asked and people just mocking me for making a mistake? Silly mistake to you, if I don't know. I simply just don't know. When I refer to people like you, is obvious to say that you have to add extra words to it. I take it as personal attack, as I am the one asking the question.

Comment: Well I really do not know what to say to you except apologize again and giving some general advice. By your other questions, I guess that you are an undergrad and as you move forward into more advanced mathematics( and hence meet more people in that field) , the likelyhood of having made fun at for mistakes in elementary high school and primary level concepts would increase proportionally. So I can only suggest that you learn to take those in a light hearted way and treat them as mere jokes and not "mockery"/"personal attacks" .

Comment: Everybody makes mistakes. I once said $\sqrt{9}=27$ infront of a packed classroom and everybody(including me) was dying laughing . I hope you are mature enough to understand that "personal attacks" are made by people who know you personally. Here we have a "community" and it should be seen as so in  the truest sense of the word. And as in any community , the exchange of one or two lighthearted jokes should not be seen as crimes .  Most people would'nt know you personally and are here to interact , talk and do mathematics. So people keep things informal as one would in a "community".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression is right, the second is not:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x^{2}}{2x^{2} + 2m^{2}x^{2}} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x^{2}}{2x^{2}(1 + m^{2})} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1 + m^{2}} = \frac{1}{1 + m^{2}}
\end{align*}

Comment: The answer is already given in the comment.

Comment: @LostinSpace I had not seen it at the time I posted my answer . . . should I delete it though?

Comment: I don't know the site policy very well.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia thank you!

Comment: @Sampaguita you are welcome!